# How to date-stamp a pickled object

Tags: python, pickle

I have a script that obtains certain information online and stores it in a list.  I'd like to keep the list for future executions of the script, and then retrieve the information online again after a certain period of time (let's say 3 days), just in case it's gone stale.  My understanding is that I can pickle the list (but please let me know if there's a more advisable way to store it -- EDIT: should I use shelve or json instead?).

My main question is this: what's the best and most idiomatic way to store the date and time of the pickle and then evaluate if 3 days have passed?

Comment: If you saved each list in a separate file couldn't you just check the file's timestamp to determine its age (regardless of the file's format)? Storing the timestamp separately — like this or another way — might be quicker than having to read the whole thing into memory just to find out how old it is. As far as what format to use goes, pickle and shelve are very Python-centric, whereas JSON is a language-independent data format (as are XML, CSV, and various other formats that can also be handled in Python via various built-in and third-party modules). File size might also be a consideration.

Comment: So you mean like Projski's suggestion below?

Comment: Yes, it's like @Projski's "Another approach".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An approach that completely avoids having to store and manage a separate file object for tracking the timestamp is to use `os.path.getmtime()` to get the date modified timestamp that linux records for the list/file that you are refreshing.

For example:

```
import os
import datetime
import time
threshold = datetime.timedelta(days=3) # can also be minutes, seconds, etc.
filetime = os.path.getmtime(filename) # filename is the path to the local file you are refreshing
now = time.time()
delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=now-filetime)
if delta > threshold:
    # do something
```

Comment: Right, but then how would I store that integer with respect to the pickled object?  Do I pickle it separately?  Do I add it as the first element of my pickled list?  Etc.

Comment: How large is your list of dates?

Comment: I don't have a list of dates.  What I want is to date-stamp when the list was retrieved and built.  But my list is several thousand entries long.

Comment: Would it be helpful if this datetime object was stored in a form that'd be human readable, or readable outside python or your script? Do you only need to store the last retrieved date, or multiple retrieval dates, a longer history?

Comment: Also, how accurate do you need to check for the age of the retrieval? Would a cron job running your script and checking once a day suffice?

Comment: Just using the pickle file's last modification time from `getmtime()` — as you mention at the end — is all that's needed (assuming there's only one list stored in it). Anything else would be redundant.

Comment: @martineau would it be better if i delete everything in my answer but the end?

Comment: I think doing that might be a good. You can also simplify the code there. In the middle this would easier: `filetime = os.path.getmtime(filename)`, `now = time.time()`, then `delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=now-filetime)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from store some data from [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org) and storing data in a pickle file.

In this example the timestamp is key from registry.

```
import json
import pickle
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.request import urlopen


url = "https://httpbin.org/ip"

with open('./dump_data.pkl', 'wb') as db:
    data = json.loads(urlopen('https://httpbin.org/ip').read())
    date = datetime.now().timestamp()
    pickle.dump(db, {date: data})
```

Comment: I don't get it.  The pickle dump doesn't seem to involve the actual data.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo! Just fixed.

Comment: Is the json used to store {date: data}, or is that just a dictionary that can be used even without json?

Comment: As you're pickling the data, you can just use dict.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is only a slight variation from other answers, but I think a good one.
If you store the `datetime` object with a separate `dump`, then you can read it independently from your data.  If your data is big, this matters.  Below, I show checking the `datetime` metadata to see if it was dumped in the last three days, and if not, then it will read the data.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> import datetime 
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> w = (1,2,3)   
>>>
>>> with open('foo.pkl', 'wb') as f:
...     pickle.dump(d, f)
...     pickle.dump(w, f)
... 
>>>
```

Now wait for three days...

```
>>> import pickle
>>> import datetime
>>>
>>> with open('foo.pkl', 'rb') as f:
...     d_ = pickle.load(f)
...     if datetime.datetime.now() - d_ >= datetime.timedelta(3):
...         w_ = pickle.load(f)
...     else:
...         w_ = None
... 
>>> d_
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 17, 6, 57, 37, 752703)
>>> w_
(1, 2, 3)
>>>
```